# Update entity from DTO with hibernate erases other fields

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, dto

I have two classes, let say

```
@Entity
public class Product{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Provider provider;
    //getter & setter
}

@Entity
public class Provider{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name
    //getter & setter
}
```

and the corresponding DTO

```
public class ProductDTO{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private ProviderDTO provider;
    //getter & setter
}
```

to simplify ProductDTO and product have the same attribute, I'm using dozer Mapping to map the entity to the DTO and send it to the view. I have a view where the user only can make changes in productDTO.name (it is an update) and when he sends the changes to the server I make something like

```
ProductServices.update(productDTO);
```

ProductServices has

```
@Transactional
public void update(ProductDTO p){
        Product p = DozerMapper.map(productDTO,ProductDTO.class);
        productDao.update(p);
}
```

inside productDao (I'm using spring so I'm injecting sessionFactory and doing, and ProductServices has the @Transactioanl annotation)

```
this.getCurrentSession().update(p);
```

So Hibernate make an update and sets provider_id=null, I know that it is right because the product that I'm sending to the ProductServices.update doesn't have provider set and Hibernate will take as the product doesn't have provider an update it in database.
Problem is that I'm not sure how can I solve this, I'm newie with hibernate and the only solutions that I found is to perform a select and check field by field and see what value has changed, but if, for example, I have a more complex object I will have to write a lot of  code to check every field.

Anybody knows a better solutions or how I can modify mi code to handle correctly this situation?

I'm using Spring 3.1 With hibernate 3.6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `ProductDTO` is an `@Entity` but the `Provider` is not? -- is this intended or an mistake?

Comment: Changed, it was a edition mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not hibernate, the "problem" is Dozer.

You need to load the entity from the database first (Hibernate). Then let Dozer only modify the fields that you want to modify (but not the id), and then let Hibernate save the updated entity.

I don't know Dozer in detail, so that this code as an raw sketch:

```
@Transactional
public void update(ProductDTO dto){
    Product p = productDao.loadById(dto.getId());
    DozerMapper.map(dto,p); //you need to configure dozer to that it only map the fields you want to map.
    productDao.update(p);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ralph, but If I do a select (loadById) before each update that would afect performance?

Comment: @UserMan: you will need to do this - there is no other way. But the performance impact will not be so huge. BTW: Almost every Web application that is based on Hibernate or JPA handle it this way.

Comment: thanks, only a final tought, what do you think if I remove DTOs and use entities directly? I use OpenSessionInViewFilter to handle lazy objects but I'm not sure if that filter is good or not.

Comment: @UserMan: thats a bad idea, because then an malicious user could send an manipulated update http-request to the server to update every field in the entity.

Comment: What if I have nested objects with ids? Is there any way to not call loadById for each nested entity? Some kind of cascade?

Answer (score 1):

This is where [Blaze-Persistence Updatable Entity Views](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.3/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#updatable-mappings-basic) come in, which support exactly this use case. It uses dirty tracking behind the scenes to know what changed and during flushing will only update these attributes. The use of entity views will improve your performance in many ways and allow you to remove a lot of boilerplate code.

The first big improvement you will see is that when an entity view is applied to a query, it will automatically only fetch the data that is really needed rather than doing lazy loading or requiring you to do fetch joins manually.

The next improvement is that updatable entity views will reduce the amount of queries necessary for doing updates. It can do the updates based on the dirty tracking information, which allows it to avoid loading data before executing DML statements.

The updatable entity views for your use case could look like this

```
@EntityView(Product.class)
@UpdatableEntityView
public interface ProductDTO {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
    ProviderDTO getProvider();
    void setProvider(ProviderDTO provider);
}

@EntityView(Provider.class)
public interface ProviderDTO {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
}
```

This will make the name and the provider reference updatable for a product. You can update it like this

```
@Transactional
public void update(ProductDTO p) {
        entityViewManager.update(entityManager, p);
}
```

Which will issue just the update statement if the name or provider reference was changed.